# How do I stop a specific sound using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I'm very new to Actionscript in general and have a slight problem.

I have two sounds playing on a frame. One is background music, the other is a noise that I only want to play on certain frames. I don't want the background music to stop, regardless of the other noise stopping.

Both sounds are inside of their own movieclip.

A visual: one frame has a stop motion on it, I would want both sounds to be playing.
          On the frame after that, I want only the background music to continue playing.

So is there anyway to make it so that only that one specific sound stops on that frame?

Comment: Do you just add sound to a frame? Do you use streaming sound mode? On what frames you have both sounds?

Comment: I have two movieclips. One contains a looped background music, the other contains a sound I only want to play on certain frames.

The sound inside of those movieclips is streamed


For example on frame 1 I won't both of those sounds to play

on Frame 2, I have a stop action that I want only the background music to play.

On frame 3, I want that second sound to play again

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you set up sound playback. If you have a frame with a sound attached which is **not streaming** it will play until the end efen if you leave this frame. But if you set it to **streaming mode** it will sync with frames and played part by part with moving frame pointer.

If you start sounds from script you should save `SoundChannel` objects returned by `Sound.play` method. Only in this case you'll be able to manually stop a specific sound since there's no global sound control.

Comment: So exactly how would I do this in terms of writing the script?

Thanks

Comment: You can't affect timeline sounds with scripts. You can only play or stop the containing MC. You might find that using a Graphic allows you to synchronize the sound better with the containing parent.